# How do I override function a with function b( C & winapi )?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Let's say that we have function A and function B, as shown below :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void  a( )
{
    printf("Hello from function a!\n");

    return;
}

void  b( )
{
    printf("Hello from function b!\n");

    return;
}

int main( )
{

    printf( "a = %p, b = %p\n", a, b );
    a( );
    b( );

    return 0;
}
```

Which in this case gives the output of :

```
a = 00401334, b = 00401349
Hello from function a!
Hello from function b!
```

Is there a way to programatically( using C and the winapi ) switch those 2 function calls from an external program to have the call to a( ) print out b's message and b( ) print out a's message with a hook of some type? If so, how would I write such a program, assuming my program is running long enough to switch the functions, and the functions aren't inlined.

Comment: In general no; these functions may be inlined, for example.

Comment: Well, assuming that they were long enough not to be inlined?

Comment: Patching the CALL instruction is technically possible.  Finding it is the hard part.  This an XY question.

Comment: @HansPassant I haven't attempted a solution yet, moreover I'm asking where to begin coding this.

Comment: "XY question" means "we don't know why you have to solve this problem".  We only know Y, no idea how you got from X (the real problem) to Y (the thing you shouldn't do).  Surely there's a better solution than patching the machine code, using a text editor is a very obvious solution.

Comment: @HansPassant, well, my original question is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19757113/how-would-i-prevent-someone-from-capturing-my-screen-in-windows. No one responded, but I still think that if I knew the API function, and was able to change the call to it, I could sucessfully modify what Skype sends as the image of my screen in screenshare.

Comment: This answer Y won't help your problem X, because any solution Y (assuming one existed) would fix only one program at a time, but you want to stop it globally. In general, redirecting internal functions in a program is not practical to do automatically due to the wide variety of ways functions can be called, many of which cannot be determined by external analysis. For example, somebody might have an encrypted function pointer which decrypts to `a`. There is no way you will figure that out without breaking their encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to learn about hook, experimenting all by yourself, you have to realize that patching/hooking is a vast and complex subject :-)

1. Do you want to patch on disk, or when the application is running?
2. Do you control the sources of the target appication?
3. Are the targeted functions located in an EXE or in a DLL?
4. In the DLL case, are the functions exported?

What I would recommend, as a starter:

Try to patch a function in your own EXE, while it is runnning, from itself (no external process involved)

1. get the address of the function (pure C/C++)
2. allocate executable memory via VirtualAlloc
3. write binary opcodes in the executable memory
4. overwrite the start of the function with a jump to your new code (saving back the overwritted part)

WARNING: you will have to know some basics about opcode, the stack, the calling conventions, etc... in particular, the overwritting of the start of the function must preserve opcode integrity of the remaining part (if you intend to jump back), that may be tricky.

Some links:

[x86 API Hooking Demystified](http://jbremer.org/x86-api-hooking-demystified/)

[MinHook - The Minimalistic x86/x64 API Hooking Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44326/MinHook-The-Minimalistic-x86-x64-API-Hooking-Libra)

[EasyHook - The reinvention of Windows API Hooking](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks, this will definitely help me learn. Also I want to patch when an application when running, without sources, in a DLL, and I'm not sure about the last question about the DLL.

Comment: @TheDelightfulEnd If your final goal is really the "skype screen sharing" problem, you should FIRST try the solution given in the first comment on your previous question: use SetWindowDisplayAffinity

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the best thing to do is just have some logic in your program that decides which function to call, based on current circumstances. You'd need to build something into your code which lets it respond to the external program in some controlled way.

Exposing or manipulating anything lower-level (such as modifying the call instruction in the binary) would be very difficult to do safely/reliably.

Comment: I realize that, but I really just posted this to learn about hooks... I know there are much more conventional ways than using a hook to overkill the situation I presented.